# How to use where statement in a dynamic column

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

i need to make a 'where' statement in a dynamic column.

the dynamic column came from a row item.
sample as below.

```
SET @paramList = STUFF((
SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + parameter + ']' 
FROM #tblitems FOR XML PATH('')
)
,1,1,'')
```

@paramList = [item1],[item2],[item3]

using the below query i need to incorporate the where statement at the end. but the column from the @paramlist should all be equal to 1 only.

```
SET @query ='select no,
' + @paramList + ' 
FROM( SELECT * FROM #tblitems)src 
PIVOT 
(
max(value)
for [parameter] in (' + @paramList + ')
) as piv order by item'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the condition string in the same way as the column list:

```
SET @condition = STUFF((
SELECT DISTINCT ' AND [' + parameter + '] = 1' 
FROM #tblitems FOR XML PATH('')
)
,1,5,'');
```

Note though that you can also use the `QUOTENAME` function instead of enclosing the name in square brackets manually:

```
SET @condition = STUFF((
SELECT DISTINCT ' AND ' + QUOTENAME(parameter) + ' = 1' 
FROM #tblitems FOR XML PATH('')
)
,1,5,'');
```

Now that you've got the condition string, you can add it to the dynamic query:

```
SET @query ='SELECT no,
' + @paramList + ' 
FROM (SELECT * FROM #tblitems) AS src 
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(value)
  FOR [parameter] IN (' + @paramList + ')
) AS piv
WHERE ' + @conditions + '
ORDER BY item;';
```